# It won't to amount to X to Y - what is the second "to" for?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

What is the second "to" here? What is this connected to?

> It won’t amount to more than the “hill of beans” in Casablanca to the world of war and peace.
>
> [Source](http://www.berfrois.com/2013/11/ron-rosenbaum-on-auden-larkin-and-love/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It won't amount to a hill of beans" is an idiom, meaning that the referenced thing will make no significant difference.

So, whatever "It" is in your sentence, it will make no difference to "the world of war and peace", which is a way of saying "the world, with regards to the chances of a war starting or a peace being established."

Put another way, the likelihood of a war starting will be unaffected by "it".

Answer (score 1):

When *amount* is used as a verb, it is usually used with *to*.

Examples from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amount+to?s=t):

> The repair bill amounts to $300.
>
> It is stated differently but amounts to the same thing.
>
> With his intelligence, he should amount to something when he grows up.

**Edit**

On the second "to", this usage is similar to the usage "It won't mean X to Y". This means Y ("the world of war and peace") won't value "it" even as much as X, even if X is something not very valuable at all.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I was a bit ambiguous here but what I wanted to know about is the second "to" ..."to the world of war and peace." What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is an allusion to Rick's speech to Ilsa near the end of the film *Casablanca*, in which Rick insists that she must leave him and get on the plane with Victor because in the larger world--a world at war, in which Victor is leading a resistance movement against Hitler and in which Rick has suddenly realized he is morally bound to take part as well--they have more important things to do than pursue their romantic attachment:

> ... It doesn't take much to see that the problems of three little people don't amount to a hill of beans in this crazy world.

So the author is saying that the love of which Auden writes is of no value to the larger world, exactly as the love of Rick and Ilsa doesn't amount to a hill of beans to **their** larger world--which is in fact the **same** world, since both Auden's 1939 poem and the 1942 film *Casablanca* are addressed to the world of World War II.